# Handling multiple forms for a single resource on a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a page on my rails application where a user can see and change his information.

For UX reasons, the page is divided into several forms. **Each form is used to update a particular set of details**, for instance there is a form for general details (name, email address), one for password changes etc.

At the moment, I have only one form, but I'd like to add a few others. What is the best way to handle this? I have two main guess but can't figure out which one would suit best.

1 - Associate an "id" to each form and add some if else statements inside my "update" action in my user controller.

2 - Create new functions (update_password, update_general_info) within my controller and have a go with the routes.

What would be the best solution and a fashionable way to design it?

Cheers

Comment: Not sure about your problem here. You can add as many forms as you like to a single page.

Comment: I do both. But when I do some testing I check some params presence ( like if params[:user][:name].present? ). Not sure one is better than another. I just do as to make my code more readable.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to give a name and value to the submit buttons for each of the forms.

```
<%= f.submit 'Update Password' %>
```

Which will render the following HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Update Password" name="commit" />
```

Then in the controller you could add a `case` or `if` to check for that parameter.

```
def update
  case params[:commit]
  when "Update Password"
    # Update the Password
  when "Update Address"
    # Update the address
  else
    # Default case
  end

  #...
end
```

The big downside here is that it couples the display HTML to the controller -- you can't change the button text without updating the controller.